# Swift 2 parse HTML and find particular nodes

Tags: swift, swift2

Using the Kanna import I am currently parsing html using the following code:

```
if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: NSURL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {

        // Search for nodes by XPath
        for link in doc.xpath("/html/head...") {
            primaryDisplay.text!=link.text!
            print(link.text)
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering how to identify specific "nodes"(not sure if that is the correct term) in/on a html page to parse the specific data I want...

Here is a image that shows what it is I wanted to know... I think...

[image]

Comment: I don't suggest you parse html that you not own. Because it could change at any time and your parser will return nil

Comment: @Anton that should not be a problem in the short term, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Anton if you write it properly thats no problem

Comment: @OP I don't get what you want... which nodes? just any of a certain type? you already have xpath right there. what is the issue?

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to get a more specific xpath... so the question is really asking for a example of a specific xpath in swift

Comment: @Daij-Djan in html i find "nodes" duplicated multiple times like example being "div" i can see 100 div "nodes" in a page of html so how would I represent the specific one i needed into the xpath?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it more clear. Of course is it possible to find specific nodes, but I doubt this is really your question.

Comment: @idmean truly my question is as simple as that I'm looking for an example of a specific (deep)node/xpath that goes beyond html/body...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath You won’t find anything better on the web.

Comment: @idmean thanks yes that was the sort of thing i was looking for i found http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp which puts it very clearly

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do what are you finding is using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

Try this:

```
do{
            let html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
                "<html>" +
                "<head>" +
                "<title>Some webpage</title>" +
                "</head>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<p class='normal'>This is the first paragraph.</p>" +
                "<p class='special'><b>this is in bold</b></p>" +
                "</body>" +
            "</html>";

            let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
            let els: Elements = try doc.getElementsByClass("special")
            let special: Element? = els.first()//get first element
            print(try special?.text())//"this is in bold"
            print(special?.tagName())//"p"
            print(special?.child(0).tag().getName())//"b"

        }catch Exception.Error(let type, let message)
        {
            print("")
        }catch{
            print("")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at xpath/xquery - it is a language specifically intended to traverse and query XML, which makes it applicable to XHTML and well HTML. XHTML is basically well formed HTML.

Assuming you had an xpath/xquery parser installed on your machine, you could...

- get a list of all the p elements in the document:  //p
- get a list of all the p elements having class "special":  //p[@class = 'special']

XQuery adds the ability to query documents using a SQL like syntax called FLWOR.

The difficulty in using this or any other parser for html is that often, the HTML is not well formed.  That means that every opening tag does not have a closing tag.  This makes any kind of parsing somewhat sketchy as the parser may not be able to figure out the hierarchy implied by the HTML.